# flutter - how to open mail/sms apps

Tags: email, flutter, sms, message

[url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) helps to draft an email, make a call and send a sms to a specific recipient. Is there any way to launch mail/sms apps (inbox - not draft) ?

Comment: I haven't tried yet since I need both Android & iOS solution.

Comment: Ok, but you can't do anything like that in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can do that in iOS but for Android, use [`android_intent`](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent) plugin and put the appropriate package_name in `data`.

```
if (platform.isAndroid) {
  AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
    action: 'action_view',
    data: 'package:com.example.app',
  );
  await intent.launch();
}
```